# How to create a JS Blob directly from an array?

Tags: javascript, blob, fileapi

I was able to create Blob from an array, either in the snippet below or in https://jsfiddle.net/z9wkfyqv/   (the snippet below can't show the proper code when viewed in its editor).

However, is there a faster way to convert the array directly into a Blob?  I found the solution first to convert it to a "Typed Array" `Uint8Array`, and then to an ArrayBuffer (the `.buffer`), and put it as the only element in the array.  Is there a more direct way to do it?

```js
const arr = [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 72, 0, 72, 0, 0, 255, 225, 0, 140, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 77, 77, 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 5, 1, 18, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 26, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 74, 1, 27, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 82, 1, 40, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 135, 105, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 160, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 160, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 120, 160, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 237, 0, 56, 80, 104, 111, 116, 111, 115, 104, 111, 112, 32, 51, 46, 48, 0, 56, 66, 73, 77, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 66, 73, 77, 4, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 212, 29, 140, 217, 143, 0, 178, 4, 233, 128, 9, 152, 236, 248, 66, 126, 255, 194, 0, 17, 8, 0, 120, 0, 120, 3, 1, 34, 0, 2, 17, 1, 3, 17, 1, 255, 196, 0, 31, 0, 0, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 255, 196, 0, 195, 16, 0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 4, 7, 6, 4, 8, 6, 115, 1, 2, 0, 3, 17, 4, 18, 33, 5, 49, 19, 34, 16, 6, 65, 81, 50, 20, 97, 113, 35, 7, 129, 32, 145, 66, 21, 161, 82, 51, 177, 36, 98, 48, 22, 193, 114, 209, 67, 146, 52, 130, 8, 225, 83, 64, 37, 99, 23, 53, 240, 147, 115, 162, 80, 68, 178, 131, 241, 38, 84, 54, 100, 148, 116, 194, 96, 210, 132, 163, 24, 112, 226, 39, 69, 55, 101, 179, 85, 117, 164, 149, 195, 133, 242, 211, 70, 118, 128, 227, 71, 86, 102, 180, 9, 10, 25, 26, 40, 41, 42, 56, 57, 58, 72, 73, 74, 87, 88, 89, 90, 103, 104, 105, 106, 119, 120, 121, 122, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 144, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 160, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 176, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 192, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 208, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 224, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 255, 196, 0, 31, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 255, 196, 0, 195, 17, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 4, 4, 135, 1, 0, 2, 17, 3, 16, 18, 33, 4, 32, 49, 65, 19, 5, 48, 34, 50, 81, 20, 64, 6, 51, 35, 97, 66, 21, 113, 82, 52, 129, 80, 36, 145, 161, 67, 177, 22, 7, 98, 53, 83, 240, 209, 37, 96, 193, 68, 225, 114, 241, 23, 130, 99, 54, 112, 38, 69, 84, 146, 39, 162, 210, 8, 9, 10, 24, 25, 26, 40, 41, 42, 55, 56, 57, 58, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 128, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 144, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 160, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 176, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 192, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 208, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 224, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 6, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 8, 10, 16, 10, 10, 9, 9, 10, 20, 14, 15, 12, 16, 23, 20, 24, 24, 23, 20, 22, 22, 26, 29, 37, 31, 26, 27, 35, 28, 22, 22, 32, 44, 32, 35, 38, 39, 41, 42, 41, 25, 31, 45, 48, 45, 40, 48, 37, 40, 41, 40, 255, 219, 0, 67, 1, 7, 7, 7, 10, 8, 10, 19, 10, 10, 19, 40, 26, 22, 26, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 255, 218, 0, 12, 3, 1, 0, 2, 17, 3, 17, 0, 0, 1, 245, 77, 181, 15, 49, 37, 62, 219, 86, 218, 190, 142, 102, 70, 167, 91, 106, 219, 106, 219, 106, 193, 43, 74, 17, 153, 217, 196, 155, 85, 65, 235, 86, 184, 151, 22, 129, 48, 27, 109, 91, 109, 91, 109, 76, 234, 47, 40, 137, 93, 223, 61, 106, 98, 212, 217, 87, 208, 45, 169, 222, 26, 251, 54, 114, 131, 109, 171, 109, 171, 109, 171, 82, 91, 214, 211, 119, 200, 17, 46, 0, 20, 196, 134, 110, 206, 87, 182, 180, 14, 133, 121, 182, 173, 182, 173, 182, 170, 218, 231, 220, 174, 89, 245, 161, 30, 232, 217, 99, 77, 121, 172, 185, 163, 208, 229, 155, 195, 84, 156, 31, 83, 93, 45, 211, 29, 182, 173, 182, 164, 249, 143, 168, 51, 23, 6, 118, 13, 223, 71, 45, 118, 102, 157, 10, 168, 180, 67, 151, 149, 215, 242, 214, 104, 157, 30, 168, 125, 154, 57, 219, 86, 219, 87, 15, 207, 250, 59, 119, 127, 63, 158, 192, 36, 243, 207, 111, 30, 27, 154, 158, 201, 156, 41, 44, 9, 43, 13, 111, 108, 85, 103, 108, 6, 219, 86, 219, 86, 219, 86, 219, 86, 219, 86, 219, 86, 219, 86, 219, 87, 255, 218, 0, 8, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 2, 236, 181, 4, 4, 44, 44, 125, 195, 50, 90, 20, 22, 159, 190, 14, 74, 182, 246, 187, 200, 190, 97, 209, 41, 182, 20, 139, 239, 76, 172, 98, 2, 130, 215, 247, 61, 166, 86, 40, 72, 197, 52, 230, 47, 239, 19, 65, 113, 69, 67, 42, 241, 142, 52, 224, 134, 191, 164, 81, 151, 152, 165, 44, 184, 145, 203, 71, 222, 185, 246, 38, 80, 141, 43, 212, 46, 84, 33, 243, 203, 140, 156, 96, 72, 72, 180, 69, 127, 152, 153, 57, 196, 64, 150, 58, 231, 26, 17, 78, 220, 36, 3, 48, 138, 198, 225, 148, 73, 252, 196, 227, 233, 208, 142, 174, 210, 13, 82, 26, 177, 72, 88, 46, 25, 57, 177, 253, 217, 21, 130, 34, 166, 11, 80, 66, 45, 166, 77, 196, 23, 178, 170, 11, 68, 44, 201, 19, 230, 133, 72, 133, 0, 168, 23, 133, 199, 221, 220, 63, 197, 162, 63, 74, 105, 68, 227, 26, 50, 238, 190, 149, 42, 224, 165, 166, 118, 133, 5, 163, 238, 110, 98, 182, 112, 200, 57, 181, 175, 98, 164, 134, 187, 216, 146, 87, 126, 41, 34, 212, 165, 241, 105, 70, 106, 218, 228, 6, 31, 184, 160, 20, 46, 237, 149, 109, 52, 83, 21, 60, 139, 154, 66, 126, 224, 14, 52, 226, 18, 84, 149, 219, 92, 38, 113, 247, 46, 173, 209, 115, 21, 204, 10, 130, 93, 126, 224, 21, 113, 199, 143, 104, 105, 144, 2, 169, 185, 90, 92, 115, 199, 33, 239, 184, 131, 44, 199, 78, 212, 37, 166, 34, 90, 82, 19, 216, 10, 184, 227, 53, 29, 161, 73, 149, 93, 215, 104, 133, 21, 109, 176, 41, 175, 107, 163, 247, 69, 165, 166, 217, 74, 113, 216, 70, 205, 172, 4, 27, 20, 134, 99, 149, 44, 71, 41, 104, 181, 12, 105, 254, 161, 255, 218, 0, 8, 1, 3, 17, 1, 63, 1, 253, 172, 154, 124, 246, 25, 84, 134, 185, 97, 184, 56, 99, 246, 246, 113, 125, 164, 118, 9, 59, 131, 185, 220, 219, 127, 75, 255, 218, 0, 8, 1, 2, 17, 1, 63, 1, 250, 117, 218, 25, 49, 79, 113, 40, 114, 75, 106, 14, 225, 125, 146, 63, 112, 118, 233, 152, 110, 14, 24, 241, 217, 77, 106, 3, 62, 205, 193, 176, 238, 1, 247, 19, 43, 111, 233, 127, 255, 218, 0, 8, 1, 1, 0, 6, 63, 2, 237, 171, 170, 126, 238, 149, 87, 201, 213, 60, 63, 152, 82, 207, 201, 63, 39, 41, 254, 87, 245, 125, 194, 148, 251, 35, 137, 245, 126, 65, 33, 138, 241, 61, 95, 125, 71, 224, 192, 117, 253, 162, 79, 125, 61, 163, 160, 96, 7, 135, 229, 30, 215, 247, 62, 253, 75, 245, 4, 143, 225, 106, 35, 141, 26, 83, 232, 41, 217, 70, 164, 80, 209, 45, 39, 209, 63, 173, 209, 34, 170, 60, 24, 79, 31, 83, 235, 247, 211, 233, 144, 171, 167, 4, 41, 67, 236, 53, 116, 245, 32, 126, 183, 66, 117, 244, 122, 70, 175, 183, 70, 107, 251, 74, 254, 22, 186, 126, 218, 139, 230, 159, 63, 103, 229, 252, 194, 146, 56, 249, 50, 61, 127, 83, 79, 145, 200, 86, 158, 90, 190, 158, 203, 79, 198, 191, 139, 199, 200, 146, 79, 202, 175, 232, 141, 62, 30, 79, 209, 67, 136, 254, 97, 70, 49, 81, 249, 254, 109, 95, 19, 94, 224, 249, 186, 62, 162, 7, 205, 133, 33, 84, 87, 145, 97, 84, 167, 168, 244, 251, 202, 87, 163, 208, 133, 122, 145, 234, 212, 165, 112, 2, 165, 199, 42, 43, 138, 198, 66, 174, 89, 35, 78, 107, 74, 106, 3, 66, 148, 49, 36, 3, 79, 78, 202, 169, 225, 163, 196, 112, 87, 240, 188, 107, 251, 207, 225, 251, 212, 245, 32, 126, 182, 41, 249, 180, 47, 86, 16, 128, 2, 70, 128, 15, 184, 170, 250, 151, 209, 228, 243, 252, 201, 213, 133, 14, 7, 95, 186, 179, 251, 61, 78, 62, 175, 205, 223, 139, 165, 74, 143, 192, 62, 159, 224, 101, 106, 243, 122, 48, 249, 94, 104, 254, 15, 186, 65, 224, 95, 45, 94, 207, 229, 87, 168, 116, 39, 169, 241, 120, 164, 252, 207, 220, 209, 252, 88, 90, 13, 20, 31, 162, 199, 20, 159, 187, 130, 254, 195, 232, 249, 114, 241, 226, 8, 243, 126, 210, 191, 31, 185, 163, 248, 247, 26, 227, 78, 4, 62, 180, 230, 61, 82, 232, 147, 213, 232, 116, 63, 113, 74, 251, 7, 220, 213, 233, 247, 146, 83, 236, 164, 215, 47, 184, 117, 80, 174, 180, 15, 243, 255, 0, 132, 254, 141, 117, 248, 44, 61, 98, 81, 254, 201, 15, 247, 52, 254, 209, 127, 75, 215, 240, 242, 116, 228, 163, 240, 127, 68, 162, 159, 129, 213, 235, 29, 127, 178, 244, 142, 159, 218, 47, 233, 78, 95, 15, 47, 245, 23, 255, 196, 0, 51, 16, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 11, 1, 17, 0, 33, 49, 65, 81, 97, 113, 129, 145, 161, 177, 193, 240, 209, 16, 225, 241, 32, 48, 64, 80, 96, 112, 128, 144, 160, 176, 192, 208, 224, 255, 218, 0, 8, 1, 1, 0, 1, 63, 33, 255, 0, 146, 207, 168, 106, 217, 185, 195, 8, 144, 143, 255, 0, 134, 74, 76, 24, 99, 49, 70, 52, 175, 255, 0, 35, 154, 83, 244, 121, 125, 255, 0, 171, 177, 120, 31, 129, 255, 0, 224, 69, 200, 208, 93, 188, 31, 221, 82, 144, 47, 93, 21, 220, 33, 84, 120, 150, 127, 252, 113, 127, 34, 143, 154, 96, 240, 101, 56, 255, 0, 208, 191, 245, 252, 215, 237, 255, 0, 54, 135, 2, 46, 49, 208, 191, 227, 252, 117, 243, 255, 0, 227, 4, 64, 14, 86, 176, 66, 104, 231, 168, 94, 160, 19, 64, 78, 11, 254, 19, 203, 74, 30, 35, 191, 207, 241, 125, 59, 73, 239, 207, 227, 251, 184, 100, 56, 30, 255, 0, 213, 51, 25, 114, 156, 174, 223, 255, 0, 31, 115, 127, 156, 255, 0, 229, 124, 17, 15, 168, 95, 207, 243, 243, 127, 202, 12, 86, 121, 126, 6, 191, 138, 167, 243, 133, 35, 128, 232, 76, 247, 188, 14, 148, 63, 118, 39, 121, 129, 227, 255, 0, 124, 254, 63, 252, 135, 97, 8, 215, 190, 171, 19, 35, 27, 219, 255, 0, 26, 164, 202, 222, 209, 9, 164, 24, 1, 202, 189, 252, 249, 255, 0, 129, 244, 207, 199, 254, 166, 167, 149, 223, 232, 251, 254, 38, 202, 144, 253, 255, 0, 174, 190, 168, 233, 237, 60, 159, 249, 239, 255, 0, 200, 135, 192, 1, 251, 30, 227, 159, 170, 167, 130, 15, 170, 113, 255, 0, 5, 234, 136, 154, 56, 48, 162, 96, 62, 84, 80, 1, 6, 243, 159, 15, 166, 144, 9, 112, 156, 174, 207, 255, 0, 17, 185, 192, 154, 214, 146, 89, 147, 237, 114, 201, 223, 1, 64, 160, 48, 228, 13, 150, 105, 121, 173, 81, 171, 158, 227, 138, 59, 87, 129, 168, 124, 89, 195, 234, 232, 255, 0, 213, 51, 224, 196, 122, 31, 235, 248, 63, 252, 72, 146, 225, 111, 136, 83, 31, 136, 131, 223, 39, 247, 102, 64, 17, 196, 176, 150, 176, 24, 21, 79, 253, 203, 96, 159, 205, 98, 213, 168, 118, 200, 238, 31, 43, 227, 106, 11, 38, 7, 215, 255, 0, 135, 227, 66, 248, 25, 105, 176, 4, 59, 190, 203, 242, 151, 148, 53, 185, 3, 157, 162, 167, 72, 245, 41, 185, 162, 114, 245, 243, 100, 96, 167, 182, 196, 32, 126, 75, 40, 189, 103, 190, 191, 235, 235, 255, 0, 194, 37, 200, 66, 121, 171, 61, 185, 190, 15, 178, 129, 52, 61, 121, 246, 95, 122, 202, 55, 208, 241, 234, 128, 0, 16, 31, 246, 70, 5, 63, 122, 245, 186, 111, 244, 250, 174, 96, 125, 200, 127, 179, 223, 255, 0, 133, 128, 251, 30, 95, 146, 190, 129, 135, 64, 60, 150, 97, 24, 120, 160, 130, 12, 63, 235, 56, 22, 36, 187, 255, 0, 18, 110, 173, 164, 189, 145, 112, 75, 224, 159, 195, 126, 164, 87, 232, 127, 252, 8, 158, 159, 172, 255, 0, 217, 161, 80, 255, 0, 195, 128, 55, 198, 10, 4, 11, 62, 42, 112, 176, 77, 16, 127, 206, 22, 74, 233, 157, 31, 254, 7, 232, 170, 80, 68, 253, 148, 45, 215, 145, 89, 50, 103, 228, 126, 79, 245, 103, 224, 251, 31, 217, 113, 143, 148, 79, 226, 111, 43, 248, 191, 251, 251, 179, 52, 39, 130, 93, 164, 190, 31, 251, 253, 220, 212, 247, 67, 252, 197, 118, 19, 216, 3, 251, 171, 63, 171, 252, 123, 251, 160, 0, 16, 31, 254, 131, 255, 218, 0, 12, 3, 1, 0, 2, 17, 3, 17, 0, 0, 16, 242, 159, 60, 215, 207, 60, 162, 239, 38, 87, 207, 60, 232, 87, 99, 243, 207, 60, 220, 191, 173, 27, 207, 60, 253, 140, 168, 19, 127, 60, 233, 49, 11, 168, 124, 252, 241, 7, 92, 212, 225, 252, 243, 207, 60, 243, 207, 60, 255, 196, 0, 51, 17, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 5, 5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 9, 1, 0, 17, 33, 49, 16, 65, 81, 97, 32, 113, 240, 145, 129, 161, 177, 209, 193, 225, 241, 48, 64, 80, 96, 112, 128, 144, 160, 176, 192, 208, 224, 255, 218, 0, 8, 1, 3, 17, 1, 63, 16, 179, 212, 207, 194, 193, 177, 46, 254, 2, 77, 130, 79, 194, 122, 103, 88, 67, 167, 224, 98, 125, 124, 201, 120, 126, 38, 20, 152, 231, 161, 130, 252, 89, 188, 144, 103, 164, 200, 158, 128, 100, 36, 130, 12, 134, 126, 143, 254, 95, 255, 218, 0, 8, 1, 2, 17, 1, 63, 16, 255, 0, 226, 158, 11, 55, 240, 157, 187, 93, 160, 166, 31, 132, 113, 180, 187, 216, 246, 28, 255, 0, 129, 10, 62, 171, 130, 233, 254, 37, 169, 142, 62, 225, 69, 248, 190, 162, 12, 243, 46, 88, 11, 38, 122, 97, 144, 159, 55, 198, 129, 244, 240, 63, 252, 159, 255, 218, 0, 8, 1, 1, 0, 1, 63, 16, 255, 0, 130, 25, 214, 0, 163, 192, 26, 215, 8, 68, 96, 7, 34, 58, 63, 254, 19, 117, 106, 50, 57, 23, 137, 245, 51, 116, 10, 9, 136, 68, 97, 17, 225, 17, 19, 215, 255, 0, 144, 57, 140, 201, 112, 30, 31, 33, 126, 61, 44, 16, 49, 151, 169, 27, 254, 190, 191, 252, 19, 20, 116, 67, 216, 221, 7, 99, 188, 59, 130, 2, 126, 0, 0, 223, 213, 91, 72, 71, 41, 163, 245, 33, 245, 255, 0, 227, 101, 177, 248, 162, 15, 220, 80, 70, 4, 63, 6, 81, 37, 203, 35, 228, 116, 253, 39, 253, 140, 160, 36, 196, 194, 239, 224, 7, 233, 103, 198, 56, 37, 149, 242, 175, 106, 202, 190, 90, 61, 138, 244, 145, 207, 200, 226, 255, 0, 163, 255, 0, 198, 88, 218, 81, 0, 121, 91, 144, 199, 137, 12, 169, 27, 61, 164, 71, 204, 103, 238, 47, 25, 224, 250, 3, 254, 72, 80, 200, 129, 242, 143, 11, 163, 103, 33, 219, 40, 120, 4, 97, 195, 133, 244, 3, 237, 86, 29, 33, 248, 124, 159, 66, 85, 240, 87, 162, 18, 22, 157, 79, 107, 248, 227, 255, 0, 199, 20, 72, 144, 158, 19, 68, 253, 212, 46, 88, 76, 72, 200, 232, 54, 71, 167, 106, 152, 230, 255, 0, 40, 31, 221, 2, 40, 36, 107, 158, 65, 47, 221, 104, 152, 121, 59, 241, 43, 250, 174, 166, 118, 224, 30, 25, 238, 159, 96, 172, 246, 183, 95, 1, 31, 138, 234, 63, 202, 84, 252, 229, 122, 135, 95, 254, 70, 246, 145, 58, 58, 191, 33, 65, 8, 34, 6, 139, 223, 176, 252, 149, 86, 44, 147, 70, 32, 250, 71, 108, 182, 45, 109, 94, 83, 171, 219, 53, 58, 154, 141, 1, 143, 104, 79, 240, 176, 176, 115, 70, 50, 71, 224, 15, 135, 165, 198, 15, 42, 39, 232, 126, 208, 247, 60, 81, 24, 197, 157, 203, 194, 121, 93, 14, 125, 34, 31, 254, 57, 70, 16, 149, 216, 32, 123, 194, 29, 152, 217, 156, 144, 74, 30, 80, 79, 236, 159, 186, 80, 139, 49, 98, 164, 136, 112, 151, 76, 49, 249, 6, 133, 206, 224, 28, 5, 208, 211, 16, 4, 253, 220, 231, 8, 211, 204, 28, 241, 39, 217, 160, 215, 168, 229, 41, 14, 39, 195, 223, 100, 61, 255, 0, 248, 128, 185, 92, 78, 88, 56, 251, 226, 133, 113, 160, 5, 179, 199, 218, 231, 89, 85, 233, 36, 18, 128, 175, 232, 161, 122, 177, 2, 38, 16, 82, 126, 27, 144, 99, 181, 136, 226, 13, 247, 158, 43, 81, 59, 114, 129, 87, 196, 212, 2, 117, 67, 65, 89, 222, 3, 12, 124, 163, 63, 94, 40, 66, 72, 160, 224, 108, 158, 33, 51, 236, 30, 218, 191, 1, 43, 198, 96, 253, 132, 127, 252, 68, 197, 72, 225, 141, 34, 125, 132, 125, 213, 200, 24, 78, 16, 43, 242, 0, 248, 79, 5, 64, 99, 80, 72, 143, 35, 64, 161, 240, 225, 16, 1, 208, 94, 51, 154, 202, 170, 237, 34, 102, 168, 232, 103, 243, 79, 210, 82, 22, 134, 188, 36, 108, 14, 52, 226, 194, 248, 61, 140, 68, 251, 102, 198, 56, 75, 180, 73, 252, 255, 0, 248, 112, 121, 30, 110, 159, 232, 27, 192, 115, 108, 9, 68, 63, 152, 189, 208, 126, 234, 134, 131, 229, 178, 159, 179, 53, 245, 76, 72, 11, 194, 153, 62, 185, 173, 36, 125, 127, 3, 20, 204, 150, 32, 214, 36, 15, 148, 156, 189, 124, 109, 65, 65, 34, 12, 128, 127, 186, 74, 196, 102, 100, 139, 11, 4, 34, 186, 156, 254, 183, 255, 0, 79, 255, 0, 8, 19, 113, 220, 4, 132, 167, 194, 153, 54, 139, 62, 18, 3, 238, 30, 233, 193, 6, 203, 143, 248, 73, 215, 226, 168, 235, 253, 223, 74, 31, 196, 15, 159, 47, 95, 60, 19, 32, 64, 4, 1, 122, 245, 255, 0, 34, 137, 43, 192, 69, 213, 111, 35, 92, 67, 228, 201, 145, 137, 14, 212, 2, 124, 36, 32, 208, 162, 82, 87, 47, 8, 246, 116, 62, 24, 68, 255, 0, 240, 195, 241, 225, 12, 176, 123, 183, 142, 18, 71, 26, 121, 16, 4, 146, 160, 238, 55, 18, 100, 123, 72, 85, 231, 79, 119, 127, 191, 221, 0, 0, 48, 2, 3, 254, 201, 66, 180, 63, 242, 75, 1, 205, 136, 56, 199, 119, 157, 106, 194, 191, 93, 61, 154, 61, 141, 110, 34, 225, 79, 181, 129, 249, 31, 171, 153, 176, 149, 80, 121, 193, 79, 102, 127, 248, 38, 242, 24, 124, 58, 71, 220, 159, 103, 139, 8, 81, 255, 0, 142, 106, 174, 13, 134, 52, 121, 238, 146, 197, 41, 209, 80, 131, 45, 19, 72, 59, 155, 2, 120, 255, 0, 142, 73, 148, 38, 74, 85, 237, 120, 83, 1, 123, 207, 255, 0, 0, 141, 77, 5, 38, 169, 36, 75, 185, 219, 98, 36, 248, 211, 248, 227, 245, 95, 224, 80, 125, 35, 63, 42, 135, 158, 96, 83, 249, 79, 213, 44, 73, 255, 0, 20, 149, 50, 48, 188, 68, 190, 73, 159, 177, 61, 20, 164, 109, 4, 161, 240, 132, 150, 119, 174, 17, 253, 172, 62, 190, 150, 16, 23, 142, 254, 18, 253, 88, 80, 255, 0, 242, 33, 95, 170, 1, 151, 202, 15, 169, 229, 246, 39, 162, 137, 96, 64, 4, 1, 255, 0, 232, 63, 255, 217];
// console.log('arr', arr);

const arrUint8 = new Uint8Array(arr);
// console.log('arrUint8', arrUint8);

const blob = new Blob([arrUint8.buffer], {
  type: 'image/jpeg'
});
// console.log('blob', blob);

const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
console.log('url', url);

document.querySelector('#my-image').src = url;
```

```html
<img id="my-image" />
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, are you looking for something like this? `new Blob([new Uint8Array(arr).buffer], {type: "image/jpeg"})`. Here's a blogpost for you to read: https://javascript.info/blob

Comment: Your code is just the same as before. I am wondering why we have to go to another data structure and then yet another data structure and finally get a Blob. Is there a way to directly get a Blob

Comment: Accessing the `.buffer` of the typed array is not a "conversion", and it can even be omitted (passing the `Uint8Array` directly as an item). But no, there's no more direct way. Why do you have binary data in a normal array in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi that's because I wanted to have data in the most basic form of JS data structure first.  So you are saying when dealing with Blobs, we should directly use typed arrays instead of a traditional array

Comment: @nonopolarity Precisely. If you want to store the data as a plain array for some reason, you must not complain about having to convert it :-)

Comment: @Bergi or I thought the Blob API might have some way to just take a plain JS array instead of needing an ArrayBuffer... or have a plain JS array give an ArrayBuffer... but is it true that ArrayBuffer is like some kind of `malloc` structure in C, so typed array is needed for this "fulled packed malloc memory region", and the `.buffer` merely spits out the pointer to the first memory location of the `malloc`

Comment: @Bergi ok I get it. The "typed array" is like `unsigned char arrUint8[123]` in C, and then the `arrUint8.buffer` is like getting the `arrUint8` address, which is conceptually closer to what a `malloc()` returns (but `arrUint8` and what `malloc()` returns are just a memory location in C. What may differ is just pointer arithmetics)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, populate directly an Uint8Array instead of a normal Array in the first step, or even better make whatever that returned this data return a Blob directly.